# Entity Framework Core Inheritance in ASP.NET Core 6 Razor pages

Tags: entity-framework-core, razor-pages

Can someone help with TPH inheritance in Razor pages?

I have two entities that inherit from a base class. In a specific situation, I need to create list of both entities with they shared and unique properties in a single table.

How (if it is possible) to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Comment: I have read the documentation, but did not find an answer to my question. It shows samples how to querry single entity, but not all. Thanks for the link.